# Post value on onsubmit and enable and disable submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to add enable and disable functionality on onsubmit or enable and disable submit button accordingly.

When I click on enable button it should be unclickable (disabled) and disable button should be clickable (enabled) and when I click on disable button the other way around-
Enable and disable functionality is working fine but I have faced one problem: When I post the value of print_r($_POST) there is nothing displayed. Why?

**JS**

```
$('input').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).get();
    toggleButtons(id);
});
function toggleButtons(id){
    // Check for attr != disabled here
    $('input').removeAttr("disabled");
    $(id).attr("disabled","disabled");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<?php print_R($_POST); ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>    
    <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>; 
  </head> 
  <body> 
     <form method="post" action=""> 
       <input type="submit" value="Button1" disabled="disabled" name="testing" id="testing"/> 
       <input type="submit" value="Button2" name="test" id="test"/> 
     </form> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: show us what you have done, and we'll surely help you...

Comment: this is html code:     <?php
 print_R($_POST);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" action="">
   <input type="submit" value="Button1" disabled="disabled" name="testing" id="testing"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Button2" name="test" id="test"/>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: dont add it as comment..please edit the question and paste the HTML there..

Comment: You cannot disable a submit button if you want to submit the form. You need a setTimeout or hide it.

Comment: [Plese check here i wanna like this:](http://jsfiddle.net/sVDYe/91/)

Comment: enable and disable button are working fine for me. i wanna post the value of input.

Answer (score 2):

I would use JavaScript to add the CSS class 'button-disabled' to it on submit, which would look like this:

**CSS**

```
.button-disabled {
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('input').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).get();
    $(this).addClass('button-disabled');
   // do other logic here
});
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this is a front end only solution.

Comment: which would be invisible if the page actually was unloaded when submitted

Answer (score 0):

1. you cannot see the disabled button if you submit the form since the page is unloaded
2. you cannot disable a submit button since it will stop the submission.

What you CAN do is to handle the submit event and post in it

Also you can use an iFrame or new window as target if you want to actually submit the form and stay on the page. Otherwise use AJAX

So

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sknrwv82/)

```
$(function(e) {
    $("form").on("submit",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // cancel actual submit
        // ajax the form
        $.post(this.action,$(this).serialize(),function() {
          alert("submitted");
        });    

    });
    $('input').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).get();
        toggleButtons(id);
    });
    function toggleButtons(id){
        var but = id;
//        setTimeout(function() { // uncomment if you want to submit to new frame/window 
            console.log("dis")
            // Check for attr != disabled here
            $('input').removeAttr("disabled");
            $(id).attr("disabled","disabled");
//        },10); // uncomment if frame/window as taget
    }        
});
```